# sqlalchemy отношения

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

[image: Примерная схема]

Товарищи, подскажите, как с помощью sqlalchemy организовать такой функционал. Есть две таблицы: категории и под категории, во второй есть ключ на первую. Когда создается компания, она должна указывать направление деятельности, но ее деятельность, может быть гораздо уже и ограничиваться несколькими элементами из этой категории. Покажите, пример, как описать классы, и чтобы можно было получить все категории компании, категории и их под категории, а так же, чтобы по (под категориям и категориям) я мог найти все компании.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

А есть ли смысл разделять категории и подкатегории? Сделайте одну таблицу категорий, у которых есть ссылка на родительскую категорию (на себя же). Это позволит произвольную вложенность подкатегорий и уберет лишнюю сущность. Получится что-то вроде такого:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

Base = declarative_base()

class Company(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'company'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Company("{}")'.format(self.name)

class Category(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'category'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('category.id'))

    parent = relationship('Category', remote_side=id, backref='subcategories')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Category("{}")'.format(self.name)

class Relationship(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'relationships'

    company_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('company.id'), primary_key=True)
    category_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('category.id'), primary_key=True)

    company = relationship('Company', backref='categories')
    category = relationship('Category', backref='companies')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Relationship({!r}, {!r})'.format(self.company, self.category)
```

Вот пример использования:

```
>>> c1 = Company(name='Google')
>>> c2 = Company(name='Yahoo')
>>> cat1 = Category(name='IT')
>>> cat2 = Category(name='Search engine', parent=cat1)
>>> cat1.subcategories
[<Category("Search engine")]
>>> cat2.parent
<Category("IT")>
>>> c1.categories.extend([Relationship(category=cat1), Relationship(category=cat2)])
>>> c1.categories
[<Relationship(<Company("Google"), <Category("IT")),
 <Relationship(<Company("Google"), <Category("Search engine"))]
>>> c1.categories[1].category.name
'Search engine'
>>> c2.categories
[]
```

Comment: Не совсем подходит в моем случае, я эти таблицы использую и в других представлениях.